# does renv really install packages isolated from r base environment?

Tags: r, renv

I have a project which I created via `rstudio` using the GUI and hitting the (New Project) button. Here are some snapshots of how i created a project with `renv`. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

[image: from r studio menu]

[image]

So far so good, `renv` has created the usual suspected files and folder:
`.Rprofile`
`renv/activate.R`
`renv/library`

It has not created `renv.lock`. I believe it's because I never called `renv::snapshot()` upon creation of the folder.

I then started to work normally on my project and installed several packages by calling `install.packages()`. For example `dplyr` is one of those packages. However I noticed that when I close the project and call `installed.packages()`  the same packages installed in my project are also installed outside. I thought `renv` works like a `conda` environment in python which `packages` are isolated from other environments. What am I missing here ? My intuition is that `renv` is not really a virtual environment like `conda` for python.

When I run `libPaths()` inside my project I get the path to `renv/library` and a `/tmp/...` path:

```
[1] "/home/alex/Documents/GitHub/CIMMYT/renv/library/R-4.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
[2] "/tmp/RtmpdfQT46/renv-system-library"
```

When I run `libPaths()` outside of my project I get:

```
[1] "/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"               
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                     
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Comment: I'd check `.libPaths()` to see what is being used at the moment. You don't mention calling `renv::init()` to start things, have you done that?

Comment: I just updated the question with `libPaths()` output. I did not call `renv::init()`. I thought `renv::init()` is called automatically using the GUI of Rstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then started to work normally on my project and installed several packages by calling install.packages(). For example dplyr is one of those packages. However I noticed that when I close the project and call installed.packages() the same packages installed in my project are also installed outside. I thought renv works like a conda environment in python which packages are isolated from other environments. What am I missing here ? My intuition is that renv is not really a virtual environment like conda for python.

The most likely answer here is that these packages were also installed into your user library, at a separate point in time.

If you can distill this into a reproducible example, you could file an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues. However, as far as I can tell everything is working as expected and the packages installed into your user library probably made their way there by some other mechanism.

Comment: is `renv::init()` called automatically when creating a project and toggling 'use renv with this project' on rstudio ? because maybe this was the problem. I did not `renv::init()`